# Letter Swap: Mammal to Bird

Tags: wordplay, letters

I originally saw this as part of a NPR word puzzle set.

Can you go from a mammal to a bird by changing only one letter?

There is at least one answer for substitution and addition that I've found (not sure about subtraction).

Comment: Doesn't seem like a unique answer, you may want to make the question more specific.

Comment: I am voting to close this puzzle as too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mammal to Avian substitution:

> Moose to Goose 
> Dog to Doo

Mammal to Avian addition:

> Cow to Crow 
>  Doe to Dove

Although there are probably more examples.

Comment: Doo? I Googled and just got dodo and bird poop.

Comment: Perhaps it's a colloquial term, see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doo#Etymology_2) edited.

Answer (score 3):

Substitution

> bull to gull

and

> seal to teal

Answer (score 2):

Mammal to Avian substitution:

> Rat to Bat (kinda)

Mammal to Avian subtraction:

> Beagle to Eagle

Comment: I'd accept beagle to eagle, but a bat isn't a bird.

Comment: isn't bat a mammal too ?

Comment: @Lordofdark marsupial, so yes.